# Matching up to first occurrence of two characters

Tags: regex

This regex expression matches up to the first semicolon:

```
^[^;]*;
```

However, I would like to match up to the first semicolon OR colon. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the chars (colon in your case) you want to stop at, inside the negated character class in the pattern you provided:

`^[^;:]*`

This regex will match any number of chars other than `;:` starting from the begining of the string

ps: this is another way to do, closer to your pattern than Raj's (and hopefully easier to understand for you)

Answer (score 3):

Use [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) form of regex.

```
^.*?[:;]
```

Add dotall modifier if there  contain any newline character present in--between,

```
(?s)^.*?[:;]
```

Comment: updated.. provide a sample input where my regex fails.